# pass data using jquery $.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to implement the following code:

html

```
   <span id = "myset">school</span>
```

Javascript

```
      var myset =$("#myset").val();
        var ID=$("#data li:last").attr("id");
    $.get('page.php', 'id='+ID+'&set='+myset, function(newdata){
        $('#data').append(newdata);

    });
```

In the page.php file, it doesn't receive the value of the $_GET['set'], but if I change

```
      var myset =$("#myset").val();
```

to:

```
       var myset ='school';
```

everything works fine in this case, what am I doing wrong, anyone could help me, thanks.
 I also tried

```
       var myset =document.getElementById("myset").value;
```

but it is still not working;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span tags don't have a value, they have `.innerText` or `.innerHTML` or, with jQuery, [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 1):

"school" isn't the value of your span. It is the data of a text node inside your span. You can access it like this:

```
var myset = $("#myset").text();
```

Comment: thanks, it works now, I need to wait a few moments to be able to click to vote your answer, can you tell me why the school isn;t the value of the span

Comment: so i couldn't use document.getElementById().value to get the value inside the tag right?

Comment: @smith value is the value property of the element. Its usually the same as the value attribute, and normally only used for form elements, such as `<input type="text" value="school" />`

Answer (score 0):

Use `var myset =$("#myset").text();` instead.